# pdf generated from dompdf not showing css styles for that template laravel 8

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I have a very weird bug that am unable to understand. am generating pdf from HTML file using dompdf in Laravel.when I view the HTML in the browser it perfectly shows all the details with the CSS styles applied in all the elements but upon generating the pdf the CSS styles disappear and the elements appear unstyled. am unable to understand the reason for this.

here is my HTML template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Total Payments For A Customer</title>
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;400;900&display=swap');

    :root {
    --primary: #e45716;
    --secondary: #b33e3e; 
    --white: #fff;
    }

    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    body{
        background: var(--secondary);
        padding: 50px;
        color: var(--secondary);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .bold{
        font-weight: 900;
    }

    .light{
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    .wrapper{
        background: var(--white);
        padding: 30px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper{
        border: 3px solid var(--primary);
        width: 700px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .logo_invoice_wrap,
    .invoice_wrapper .header .bill_total_wrap{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 30px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .logo_sec{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .logo_sec .title_wrap{
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .logo_sec .title_wrap .title{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: var(--primary);
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .logo_sec .title_wrap .sub_title{
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .invoice_sec,
    .invoice_wrapper .header .bill_total_wrap .total_wrap{
        text-align: right;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .invoice_sec .invoice{
        font-size: 28px;
        color: var(--primary);
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .invoice_sec .invoice_no,
    .invoice_wrapper .header .invoice_sec .date{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .invoice_sec .invoice_no span:first-child,
    .invoice_wrapper .header .invoice_sec .date span:first-child{
        width: 70px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .invoice_sec .invoice_no span:last-child,
    .invoice_wrapper .header .invoice_sec .date span:last-child{
        width: calc(100% - 70px);
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .header .bill_total_wrap .total_wrap .price,
    .invoice_wrapper .header .bill_total_wrap .bill_sec .name{
        color: var(--primary);
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .table_header{
        background: var(--primary);
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .table_header .row{
        color: var(--white);
        font-size: 18px;
        border-bottom: 0px; 
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .row{
        display: flex;
        border-bottom: 1px solid var(--secondary);
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .row .col{
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .row .col_no{width: 5%;}
    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .row .col_hse{width: 20%;}
    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .row .col_payment{width: 20%; text-align: center;}
    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .row .col_date{width: 20%; text-align: center;}
    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .row .col_arrears{width: 15%; text-align: right;}
    .invoice_wrapper .body .main_table .row .col_overpayment{width: 20%; text-align: right;}

    .invoice_wrapper .body .paymethod_grandtotal_wrap{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 5px 0 30px;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .paymethod_grandtotal_wrap .paymethod_sec{
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .paymethod_grandtotal_wrap .grandtotal_sec{
        width: 30%;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .paymethod_grandtotal_wrap .grandtotal_sec p{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .paymethod_grandtotal_wrap .grandtotal_sec p span{
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .paymethod_grandtotal_wrap .grandtotal_sec p span:first-child{
        width: 60%;
        background: var(--primary);
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .paymethod_grandtotal_wrap .grandtotal_sec p span:last-child{
        width: 40%;
        text-align: right;
        background: var(--primary);
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .body .paymethod_grandtotal_wrap .grandtotal_sec p:last-child span{
        background: var(--primary);
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .footer{
        padding: 30px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .footer > p{
        color: var(--primary);
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .invoice_wrapper .footer .terms .tc{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="invoice_wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo_invoice_wrap">
                <div class="logo_sec">
                    <img src="/imagesforthewebsite/webicon.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="W.karanja WebApps Realtors">
                    <div class="title_wrap">
                        <p class="title bold">W.karanjaWebApp Realtors</p>
                        <p class="sub_title"> Limited</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{-- <div class="invoice_sec">
                    <p class="invoice bold">RECEIPT</p>
                    <p class="invoice_no">
                        <span class="bold">Receipt No</span>
                        <span>{{ $paymentdetails->receipt_number }}</span>
                    </p><br>
                    <p class="date">
                        <span class="bold">Date Receipt Generated</span>
                        <span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($paymentdetails->created_at)->format('d/m/Y')}}</span>
                    </p>
                </div> --}}
            </div>
            <div class="bill_total_wrap">
                <div class="bill_sec">
                    <p class="bold">Tenant Details</p> 
                    {{-- Name:<p>{{ $userdetails->name }}</p> --}}
                    <span>
                        Name:{{ $userinfor->name }}<br/>
                        Phone Number:{{ $userinfor->phone }}<br/>
                       Id Number:{{ $userinfor->id_number }}<br>
                        Rooms:@foreach ($userinfor->hserooms as $room )
                            {{ $room->room_name }},
                        @endforeach
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="main_table">
                <div class="table_header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col_no">Id.</div>
                        <div class="col col_hse">House Details</div>
                        <div class="col col_payment">Amount Paid</div>
                        <div class="col col_date">Date Of Payment</div>
                        <div class="col col_arrears">Arrears</div>
                        <div class="col col_overpayment">Over_Payment</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table_body">
                    @foreach ($viewuserpayments as $userpayment)
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col_no">
                                <p>{{ $userpayment->id }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col_hse">
                                <p class="bold">{{ $userinfor->rentalhses->rental_name }}</p>
                                <p>@foreach ($userinfor->hserooms as $room )
                                    {{ $room->room_name }},
                                @endforeach</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col_payment">
                                <p>{{ $userpayment->amount_paid }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col_date">
                                <p>{{ $userpayment->date_paid }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col_arrears">
                                <p>{{ $userpayment->total_arrears }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col_overpayment">
                                <p>{{ $userpayment->overpaid_amount }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="paymethod_grandtotal_wrap">
                <div class="paymethod_sec">
                    {{-- <p class="bold">Our Payment Methods</p>
                    @foreach ($paymenttypes as $type)
                        <p>{{ $type->name }}:{{ $type->number }}</p>
                    @endforeach --}}
                </div>
                <div class="grandtotal_sec">
                    <p class="bold">
                        <span>Total Arrears</span>
                        <span>{{ $totalArrears }}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="bold">
                        <span>Total Over Payments</span>
                        <span>{{ $totalOverpayments }}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Thank you For Paying your Rent</p>
            <div class="terms">
                <p class="tc bold">Terms & Coditions</p>
                <p>Your Payment has been paid to XYZ Company.Click <a href="/">here</a> to visit the Company website</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the function in the controller

```
  // download all payments made by a user
public function downloaduserpayments(Request $request,$id)
{
    $viewuserpayments=AllUsersPayment::where('user_id',$id)->get();
    $userinfor=User::where('id',$id)->first();
    $totalArrears=$viewuserpayments->sum('total_arrears');
    $totalOverpayments=$viewuserpayments->sum('overpaid_amount');

    $data = [
        'viewuserpayments'=> $viewuserpayments,
        'userinfor' => $userinfor,
    ];

    view()->share($data);
    $totalpaymentspdf=app()->make(PDF::class);
    $totalpaymentspdf->loadView('Admin.tenantpayments',$data); 
    return $totalpaymentspdf->download('Total Payments For a User.pdf');
}
```

Comment: pdf packages does not support all css properties, read the official documentation of the package that you are using to know it's limitations